# Incrementing each row in excel that contains a number

Tags: excel

I was sent an excel document in the following format:

```
A |  B  |
1 | abc |
  | def |
2 | abc |
  | def |
  | ghi |
3 | abc |
  | def |
```

So basically I have the first column which contains ordered numbers every couple of rows. I want to insert a row e.g. between 2 and 3, so that the new row will be numbered 3, and the rows below it are updated accordingly i.e. 3 becomes 4, 4 becomes 5 and so on.

I don't really use excel, but I am curious if there is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: in which language you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In A1, enter the following formula:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(A1),2)=1,(ROW(A1)+1)/2,"")
```

And copy that formula down to the bottom of the range. Each time you insert a new row, you will need to manually copy the formula to the inserted row's first cell.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a pattern in the b column, to distinguish if you need to jump to the next number? 
if so use:
in cel A2 and further:

```
=IF(B2 = "abc",A1+1,A1)
```

With conditional formating, hide the repeating numbers: `=A2=A1`

Comment: The B column contains descriptions, so each row will be different. It was solved above, but thanks for the help! :)